# How to allow double quotes in URL?

Tags: asp.net, regex, url, url-rewriting

How to allow double quotes in URL  i am using  URL rewrite module but it negates the double quote

here is URL rewrite  rule

```
<match url="^([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-‘!@#$%^*()!~`\'?&quot;]+)"/>
```

Comment: Hint: this `[&quot;]` can match `&`, `q`, `u`, `o`, `t`, or `;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to match a double quote is by using a hex representation: `\x22` or `\u0022`:

```
<match url="^([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-‘!@#$%^*()!~`\'?\x22]+)"/>
                                                                   ^^^^
```

or

```
<match url="^([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-‘!@#$%^*()!~`\'?\u0022]+)"/>
                                                                   ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 4):

You simply can't allow it. It would read it as flat text.. It's certainly not recommended to use "" in a URL. If you really want to use it try using: %22 instead of ".